# Delete entity and delete only reference_fk in other table without remove the second entity

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have my table Person and she is link with Table B,C,D...Z and more
If I want to remove one data in my Table Person, I have an error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

It's normal okay, but when I put in annotation onDelete="Set NULL"

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Personne", inversedBy="mandats")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personne_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     **/
    protected $personne;
```

And do doctrine:schema:update --force I have this error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I saw something like cascade = true, onDelete=true or orphanDelete= true but in each case the table where the fk is, will be remove ?

In my case, I just want remove one Person and remove the reference in other tables without remove these entities

There is an option, to do one by one in sql alter and drop foreign key I think, but imagine there is 500 table there is an alternative ?

Its works with heidisql without probleme but with php command nop !

There is the context

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make sense, an FK applies over the entire table not to a specific row.

Comment: I know, but the reference is in one row in second table and the second table have other FK so I can't remove this one and there is 50 second one..., do you have some options ?

Comment: @P.Salmon I fixed the probleme, it was onDelete=set Null but in every Entities associate in sametime !! I did this only on 1 entity to test there is the origin of my error !!
and do schema update et play command and OK